# Replacing char on the end of string

Tags: c#

I'm Adding strings in loop and for each loop I need to check whether it doesn't cantains `/` on its end.

e.g. `www.google.com/` needs to result in `www.google.com`

but for `www.google.com/maps` needs to result in `www.google.com/maps`

```
serviceLink.Add(row.LinkService.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ").Replace("http://",""));
```

May someone please help me solve thi out?

I thought that `.Replace(".com/",".com")` would be enough but it wouldn't handle other domains.

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: You could use the `Uri` class instead of parsing the string yourself. What if it starts with `"https://"`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
myString = myString.TrimEnd('/');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str = "www.google.com/";//or any other link
    int index=str.Trim().LastIndexOf("/");
    if (index == str.Trim().Length - 1)
        str=str.Remove(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.String MyStr="http://www.google.com/";
if(MyStr.EndsWith("/"))
{
   MyStr = MyStr.Substring(0, MyStr.Length - 1);
}
```